# Passing xargs values as argument to subsequent YARN command

Tags: linux, hadoop, grep, hadoop-yarn, xargs

Need help with passing arguments from xargs to subsequent Hadoop command.

I have results like below from this command.

```
yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING | grep <user> | awk '{print $1}'
```

Results of above command as below.

```
17/09/19 12:24:36 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider:
Failing over to rm21 Total Application-Id
application_1505017974932_14847 
application_1505017974932_14815
application_1505017974932_14810 
application_1505017974932_14784
application_1505017974932_14796 
application_1505017974932_14778
```

I need to be able to pass above output one by one to below command.

```
yarn application -movetoqueue <application_ID of above output> -queue myqueue
```

Could you please help here in finding the right command to achieve the same?

Similar setup is working for me in below command but not in the above as above command has n

a)

```
yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING | grep <user> | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -n 1 yarn application -kill
```

This is another way..

b.) for app in `yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING | grep <user> | awk '{print $1}’`; do yarn application -kill "$app";  done

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 2):

**`xargs`** reads the **`STDIN`** stream data and converts each line into space separated arguments to the command. 
Some reasons why xargs might not work in your case:

1. Using xargs, the argument to this command *"yarn application
   -movetoqueue 'application_ID' -queue myqueue"* is passed at the end of it.
2. Not all the applications/tools accept multiple space separated
   arguments.
3. The result of your command is a string containing special characters and it should be quoted.

So, I would suggest the following:

```
for appid in `yarn application -list -appStates RUNNING | grep user|awk '{print $1}'` ; do 
    yarn application -movetoqueue "${appid}" -queue myqueue;
done
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much for your syntax, It is WORKING with for loop command. Much Appreciated.

Comment: @ Ardit,Could you pls check if below can also be worked in same fashion ?for appid in `oozie job -info 0007218-170910003406158-oozie-oozi-W | grep job | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c4-23 | sed 's/job/application/'`; do yarn logs -applicationId "${appid}" -Owner user9; done

Comment: for loop is suposed to take variables from your command output expression, so you should put the command within $()

`for appid in $(oozie job -info 0007218-170910003406158-oozie-oozi-W | grep job | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c4-23 | sed 's/job/application/'); do yarn logs -applicationId "${appid}" -Owner user9; done`
You are using too many tools in your command, you can do it only with `awk` or `sed` only. In case you have other queries, please post more information (input, desidered output).

Comment: New to this, Where to  mark this question as completed ? Also, can you pls take a look at this. post https://stackoverflow.com/q/46372820/4447530