# Using for loop to pass arguments to command

Tags: hadoop, for-loop, sh, hadoop-yarn

I have below command that produce this output

Command:

```
oozie job -info 0007218-170910003406158-oozie-oozi-W | grep job | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c1-23 | sed 's/job/application/'
```

Output:

```
application_1505017974932_23474
application_1505017974932_23478
application_1505017974932_23477
application_1505017974932_23473
application_1505017974932_23475
application_1505017974932_23471
application_1505017974932_23469
application_1505017974932_23476
application_1505017974932_23472
application_1505017974932_23470
application_1505017974932_23495
application_1505017974932_23497
application_1505017974932_23500
application_1505017974932_23501
```

I need to pass these output lines as input to below command along with storing the log file in /tmp folder

`yarn logs -applicationId <applicationID> -Owner <userID> > /tmp/<applicationID>.txt`

Trying to automated this with one single syntax using for loop but facing challenges. The current for loop that is having issue is below

```
for appid in `oozie job -info 0007218-170910003406158-oozie-oozi-W | grep job | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c4-23 | sed 's/job/application/'`; do yarn logs -applicationId "${appid}" -Owner user9 > /tmp/ "${appid}"; done
```

Currently am getting error as below

```
Invalid ApplicationId specified
Invalid ApplicationId specified
Invalid ApplicationId specified
Invalid ApplicationId specified
Invalid ApplicationId specified
```

Usually we will get this if we don't specify right applicationid as parameter.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, it is not at all clear. Please let us know more specific details in code tags for sample Input_file and expected output too.

Comment: Why are you now using `cut -c4-23`?

Comment: am using cut -c4-23 to get only required text from output

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Not sure what is meant by code tags ?